# Docker compose error: compose.cli.main.main: Container command could not be invoked

Tags: docker, haproxy, docker-compose, boot2docker

I am trying to run haproxy in a docker container. To build and run the haproxy from the image, docker-compose reads my .yaml file below.

```
proxy:
    build: ./
    env_file: .env
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    - "9000:9000"
```

After executing a docker-compose build, the image is created but while trying to spawn a container using the following, I am getting the following errors:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting my_haproxy_container
←[31mERROR←[0m: Container command could not be invoked.
```

By docker install information:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 22:37:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I am not sure why the `docker-compose up -d` is unable to bring up the container. Any information is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Container command could not be invoked
>   Is means you have problems with CMD in your Dockerfile. It is not docker-compose problem.

- Incorrect CMD command
- Command in CMD tries to run file without -execute permission

Check you ./Dockerfile